# When return statement, comma operator, braced-init-list and std::unique_ptr come together

Tags: c++

In the code below, why do I get compilation error for `n = 8` whereas all other cases are OK? My intent was to report some error and return empty pointer without cluttering the code with unnecessary braces. I will use nullptr for this purpose but I'm curious why `{}` fails to compile with comma operator whereas it works alone.

You can play with this code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/NaNHYe). I used C++20 setting.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

void oops(const char*) {
}

std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> please_do(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>(); // compiles ok
    if (n == 2)
        return oops(""), std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>(); // compiles ok

    if (n == 3)
        return std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(n); // compiles ok
    if (n == 4)
        return oops(""), std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(n); // compiles ok

    if (n == 5)
        return nullptr; // compiles ok
    if (n == 6)
        return oops(""), nullptr; // compiles ok

    if (n == 7)
        return {}; // compiles ok
    if (n == 8)
        return oops(""), {}; // why compilation error?

    return nullptr; // compiles ok
}

int main() {
    please_do(42);
    return 0;
}
```

GCC 9.2 output:

```
<source>: In function 'std::unique_ptr<unsigned char []> please_do(int)':

<source>:26:26: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token

   26 |         return oops(""), {}; // why compilation error?

      |                          ^

<source>:26:25: error: expected ';' before '{' token

   26 |         return oops(""), {}; // why compilation error?

      |                         ^~

      |                         ;
```

Clang 9.0.0 output:

```
<source>:26:16: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'void' to function return type 'std::unique_ptr<uint8_t []>'

        return oops(""), {}; // why compilation error?

               ^~~~~~~~

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:528:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'void' to 'std::unique_ptr<unsigned char [], std::default_delete<unsigned char []> > &&' for 1st argument

      unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& __u) noexcept

      ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:533:12: note: candidate constructor template not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'void' to 'std::nullptr_t' (aka 'nullptr_t') for 1st argument

        constexpr unique_ptr(nullptr_t) noexcept

                  ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:681:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'void' to 'const std::unique_ptr<unsigned char [], std::default_delete<unsigned char []> > &' for 1st argument

      unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;

      ^

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:542:2: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'unique_ptr<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'void'

        unique_ptr(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) noexcept

        ^

<source>:26:24: error: expected expression

        return oops(""), {}; // why compilation error?

                       ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{}` is not an expression. `return {...};` is its own special syntax (a form of [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)) that figures out the return type from the function's signature, as if by `Ret{...}` where `Ret` is the return type:

```
Ret f() {
    return {...}; // special syntax for return; {args...} need not be a valid expression
}
// same as
Ret f() {
    return Ret{...}; // generic return <expression> syntax; Ret{args...} must be a valid expression
}
```

There is no special syntax in `return a, b`. It's just the expression `a, b` being returned using the normal `return` syntax. The comma operator requires both `a` and `b` to be expressions, but since `{}` is *not* an expression, expressions like `oops(""), {}` is invalid syntax.

As an aside, there are other places where `{...}` can be used that make it look like it's an expression when it's actually not, e.g. function calls:

```
void f(std::string);
f({5, 'a'})
```

Again, though this looks like `{5, 'a'}` is an expression with type `std::string` (as is the intention), it is not. The `{5, 'a'}` is part of the function call itself, and its type is decided by overload resolution.

As to the compiler errors, both of them are being confused by the fact that `oops(""), {}` is invalid syntax as an expression. GCC appears to have read `oops(""),`, and is thus expecting an expression to follow. But expressions cannot start with `{`, so it reads that character and immediately barfs, complaining that it was expecting an expression to begin. Clang does the same thing. I think that Clang then continues, in its quest to be "helpful", to pretend that you just didn't write the `, {};` part (that is, as if you wrote `return oops("");`), and issues an error for that, too. This behavior is e.g. what allows Clang to provide useful type errors even if you misspell something; that is, if you were to run Clang on

```
void supercalifragilisticexpialidocious(std::string);
int main() { supercalifragilisticexpialidociuos(7); }
```

it would first issue an error for the bad spelling (`-ous -> -uos`), suggest the correct spelling, and then it would issue an error for the type mismatch between the `int` `7` and the argument type `std::string` as if you had already fixed the spelling. Similarly, here, it's issuing one error for the bad syntax and then a second error as if you had gotten rid of the bad syntax. However, it's not very helpful in this case since the "fix" it imagines you using is not the actual fix.

Comment: Thanks! Do you find error messages meaningful in GCC and Clang? I find them confusing. What `primary-expression` expects GCC? Why Clang refers to return type of `oops()` if it should discard its value? Can you please add this to the answer?

Answer (score 2):

`{}` has no types, so with comma operator `oops(""), {}` is wrong.

`return {};` has special treatment with [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Comment: Thanks! Do you find error messages meaningful in GCC and Clang? I find them confusing. What `primary-expression` expects GCC? Why Clang refers to return type of `oops()` if it should discard its value? Can you please add this to the answer?

Comment: `return oops(""), {};` is wrong, as second operand should be expression and `{}` is not (both reports that error (first for gcc, last for clang)). Continue after error (to report all error) is difficult. Clang supposes that intent is `return oops(""); ERROR` but `return oops("");` is also an error with incompatible return type.

Comment: Aha, it explains why it refers to return type of `oops`. As to `primary-expression` I still don't get it. If `primary expression` is expression before comma, then there seems nothing wrong with it: function call is expression, right? The problem is with secondary expression?

Comment: comma operator requires that both operand are expression, `{}` is not. So we have `oops(""), ERROR_NotAExpression`.